# Clear dataframe cell if it does not contain a word from list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tokenize

I have a dataframe with tokenised text that looks like the following:

```
index  id    text1                   text2        
1      123   ['it', 'was', 'cold']   ['i', 'wasn't', 'there']   
2      124                           ['hello', 'there'] 
3      125   ['the', 'heat']         ['the' 'cold']     
4      126                           ['the', 'heat']
```

and a list with words about the weather, for example `lst = ['heat', 'cold', 'rain']`

What I want is to clear a cell in the dataframe if it does not contain a word from the list. So the dataframe would look as follows in the end:

```
index  id    text1                   text2        
1      123   ['it', 'was', 'cold']   
2      124                            
3      125   ['the', 'heat']         ['the' 'cold']     
4      126                           ['the', 'heat']
```

So far I have only found solutions that clear the whole row when a word isn't found, but I want the dataframe to stay intact and especially keep the id column!!

Another problem I want to solve is that it would be great to be able to label the columns. In this case I can split up the list for example into `pos=[heat, sun]` and `neg=[cold, rain]`. So, the output would be:

```
index  id    text1                  label1   text2           label2  
1      123   ['it', 'was', 'cold']  neg 
2      124                            
3      125   ['the', 'heat']        pos      ['the' 'cold']  neg
4      126                                   ['the', 'heat'] pos
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['heat', 'cold', 'rain']
df.iloc[:,2:] = df.iloc[:,2:].applymap(lambda x: x if set(x.split()).intersection(lst) else '')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
index   id        text1     text2 text3
1      123  it was cold                
2      124                             
3      125     the heat  the cold      
4      126      my bike  the heat
```

Comment: Hi! You're solution didn't completely work for my problem (some items weren't deleted or items that didn't have any overlap stayed or the wrong columns were taken etc.). I have made some changes in my code and updated my question, would you be able to help me with the updated problem?